# What happens when a bounty expires?

Tags: discussion

Are bounty points taken from reputation regardless of whether there is an answer during the bounty period or not? I looked through FAQ and could not find the answer to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You lose the points as soon as you open a bounty. No takebacks (except in extraordinary circumstances)

- If you assign a "winner" the points go to that person.
- If you do not assign a winner:

  - but someone who post after the bounty was opened got at least 2 upvotes (and has the most of such qualifying answers), they will automatically receive half the points.
  - If nobody qualifies as an auto-winner then the points are just lost.

Comment: See also [Everything you never wanted to know about the bounty system and couldn't find because the mSO search system sucks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @voretaq7 Wow, I typed almost that exact title into mSO search and it still didn't come up...

Comment: Thanks. I have no problems giving up the points. This is a question that alludes an answer.

Comment: yeah, google::`Stack Exchange bounty` found it for me.  I really have given up on the site search. Google does it better.

Comment: Despite Jeff's claims to the contrary the site search has always sucked big time. They may as well remove it and just whack a Google search box in its place.

Comment: I am quite sure the site search problem is the dreadful "Microsoft disease". The microsoft.com site has it as well (and had it for what feels like decades now). It surely is contagious and apparently transferred by unsuspecting employees who are leaving Microsoft and starting different jobs (or start-ups). The employees themselves develop no symptomps, but the company's site search function is screwed forever.

Comment: @john or you could just read http://serverfault.com/faq#bounty which is linked from, y'know, the faq, which is linked approximately one bazillion different places. We can lead horses to water..

Comment: @Jeff, either you're replying to the wrong person or the wrong question. My comment above refers to the site search, not bounty. As for the question, I didn't ask it.

Comment: @john my point is that *search is irrelevant* all one needs to do to understand bounties is **read the site FAQ!** http://serverfault.com/faq#bounty Therefore, your comment is also irrelevant. Search is the wrong approach here; reading the FAQ is the correct one. The FAQ *directly* answers the question and is linked from thousands of places on the site..

Comment: @vore you need to read the above, too

Comment: @JeffAtwood The FAQ has a good reference on how to create bounties, and as you point out the answer to octo's question is in there (though maybe not as obvious as it should be when you look at the FAQ index - how does a newbie know bounties are "what you do if you don't get a good answer"?). That mSO answer has lots of *extra* information beyond what's in the FAQ, and my comment on search is along the lines of "There's more to know here, but our (meta) site search tools have a hard time turning up this additional information. Here's a link courtesy of Google."

Comment: @vore point taken on the section title. It wasn't the newbies I was really referring to, but those who hold diamonds. The mods most of *anyone* should know the faq cold, and if they don't.. everyone is screwed.

Comment: Bounties, in my experience, are what you do when you don't get a good answer AND wish to throw away some of your earned points.  I don't care much about points, but can't understand why getting no answers warrants losing the bounty into the ether.