# What happens when you place a bounty and there are no answers?

Tags: discussion, support

Wondering what the process is when you offer a bounty on one of your own questions and there are still no answers?

Asking this because this has just happened to [one of mine](https://serverfault.com/questions/658892/issue-with-offline-availability-of-roaming-profiles)

Answer (score 2):

Well, nothing.

The rep you offered is gone.  And you have no answers, and thus no one you can award those fake internet points to.

Comment: Reputation on serverfault are not fake internet points, they are real internet points.

Answer (score 2):

From the [bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/bounty) page:

> All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any
>   circumstances.

Comment: @Chris-S makes the point here that there are "No takebacks (except in extraordinary circumstances)" http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3191/what-happens-when-a-bounty-expires

Comment: @noonand Unfortunately, not getting an answer is not an extraordinary circumstance. Those are things like, say, having to close or delete the question despite the bounty (which is _very_ rare).